# How to customise TFS2010 build to print a message in the log

Tags: tfs, msbuild, workflow-foundation-4

I have recently migrated one of my solution from SVN+CruiseControl to **TFS2010**. My build definition is using the Defaul Template. And I would like to customise the template. Since I have never worked with workflows before I decided to start by printing a simple message in the build log. For this purpose, I have added a **WriteBuildMessage** activity right on the top of the sequence as its first activity and given it a value of Hello World. However after saving it, checking it in the source control, queuing, completing a new build and then opening the build, I do not see the Hello World message any where in the View Log, Sumary tab or msbuild log file. I have tried putting the **WriteBuildMessage** activity at different places in the workflow but it just never gets printed. I can ensure that my build definition is pointing to the correct template but it just doesn't seem to print the message, as if it has never run the **WriteBuildMessage** activities in the workflow?

Is there somethign I am mising or is **WriteBuildMessage** is not the correct activity to print a message in the log Any ideas?

Regards,

Nabeel

Answer (score 4):

I figure it out via MSDN forums

1. If you want the output from WriteBuildMessage to be visible in the default logging level, you must set the **Importance** property to **BuildMessageImportance.High**.
2. The default Importanceof WriteBuildMessage is Normal so that the message will not be displayed. When you queue a build, in the parameters tab, set Loggong Verbosity to Diagnostic and then all message will be showed, but this will create much more noise in the build log.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsbuild/thread/1a6bbc05-8bd3-40f5-ab38-667214e5fe01